# Remove Data from Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column that contains names

In some records it will have items like the following:

Smith, John(2) or Smith, John(2)(3) or Smith, John,(2)(3) or Smith, John,

I want to clean up the data to remove anything in parentheses and the parentheses themselves and the end comma from this data. The end results should look like Smith, John once these are corrected. The names are varying length.

Comment: How about to sorting the data?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable question to me.  Whomever marked down the question, please state why you did it.

Answer (score 1):

in a new column, put the formula

=LEFT(A2;FIND("(";A2)-1)

(Assuming A2 is your cell with the Smith-john stuff)
and copy it down for all rows. It will find the first parenthesis-open and remove everything behind.

If the result looks good, copy the result column, and paste over your data with *'Paste Special/Values'* (not the normal 'Paste'!).

Comment: That worked PERFEFCT..BUT when I copied it down through, the cells that didn't have the "(" have a #VALUE! error. How do I add IF Else sort of stament?

Comment: =IFERROR((LEFT(A2;FIND("(";A2)-1);A2)

Answer (score 1):

For the parentheses and contained values, you could use `FIND/REPLACE` with a wild card in the find string:  `(*)`.

For the terminal comma, you'd need a formula -- just check the last character

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1) = ",",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Text-to-Columns feature and set it manually to break (deliminate) on `(` bracket.

Similarly for the comma, use the Text-to-Columns feature and break on the `,`, but you will then need to recombine first and lastname columns.